# Vista previa de una imagen al ingresar un link

Tags: javascript, imagen

Tengo un formulario para crear un usuario con un input de tipo text para ingresar el *link* de una imagen online, y necesito que al pegar el *link*, se muestre la imagen donde esta señalando.

Anteriormente lo estaba haciendo con un input tipo file que funcionaba de maravilla y estaba usando jquery, pero no funciona ahora que es un *link online*.

Este es el input de tipo text

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="photo_ud">Photo Link Online</label>
     <input type="text" name="photo_id" id="selectImage">
</div>
```

Y este es donde se debe mostrar la vista previa:

```
<div class="user-avatar-container">
     <img id="prevImage" src="/images/default-user.png" alt="">
</div>
```

El formulario se ve así:

[image: imagen del formulario]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de forma simple con un `addEventListener` que asigne la `url` al `src` del elemento al cambiar el valor del input:

```js
document.getElementById('selectImage').addEventListener("change", function(){ 
  document.getElementById('prevImage').src=this.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="photo_ud">Photo Link Online</label>
     <input type="text" name="photo_id" id="selectImage">
</div>

<div class="user-avatar-container">
     <img id="prevImage" src="/images/default-user.png" alt="" width="200">
</div>
```

Comment: En lugar del evento `change`, puedes usar el evento `input`. Eso mejora el hecho de que haya que perder el foco del input para que active el `change`

Comment: @Emeeus gracias por la sugerencia, es cierto, solo use `change` por que es mas común.